# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding an election for moderators for Operations Research.

The last election we held was back in 2019 when we elected EhsanK, LarrySnyder610, and TheSimpliFire.

So to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts, if we decide to go for it.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, June 13th (with question collection starting on June 6th) is the tentative date for such an election, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

Comment: Hi Vanny! I am curious to know how these dates get decided, since last week a [similar post on Tor.Meta](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/387/28306) listed 7 February (4 days from now, yikes!!!) as the tentative date for the election, but this post suggests 1 June (which in my opinion, is a timeframe that makes a lot more sense!).

Comment: That post should have been deleted, as this one was meant to be the post, thanks for catching that. It has been deleted. But actually, the election should start on June 6th, with question collection. So I corrected that. @NikeDattani

Answer (score 6):

If we need more mods, I'm willing to be one, but I would be just fine letting someone else do the work (a statement that generalizes beyond the immediate context). Is there a guideline for the "right number" of mods on a site? Is it just not having existing mods drop from exhaustion?

Comment: +1. By default, sites typically would have 3 diamond mods. It can drop below that for some time (and indeed some sites currently have only 2 diamond mods, and others have had 1 or 0 for a surprisingly long time), but usually these diamond mods will get replaced in subsequent elections. A site can have more than 3 diamond mods in some circumstances, for example when the current team feels that they need more help.

Comment: Just a note that I would very much support your nomination, should you wish to do so.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks! As long as we have three qualified candidates, I'm content to let others do the work. :-)

Comment: @prubin Well, it’s just that for the election to proceed we need more than 3 candidates, as otherwise there will be no election :p (edit: there’s now four, but as you are one of the most active members of this community, you would make a very strong case).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire OK, I just self-nominated.

Comment: @prubin Good to see your nomination!

Comment: Thanks, and congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

I am planning to step down as moderator and not run during the upcoming election. I've enjoyed being a mod and plan to still contribute to the site (including community moderation), but my attention has been pulled away by several other things, and I think someone else could do a more thorough and reliable job than I could in the moderator role. I hope some folks are interested in running!

Answer (score 0):

I've been around from the start, helping a lot during the startup and helping out from time to time here and there since the first few months after the first election.

If we are short one, count me in.